# Pass arguments correctly to function which returns a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a function in one seperate file which returns a new function.

```
const myFunc = (a, b) => (c) => console.log(a, b, c);
```

I want to send down some values as `a` and `b`. And this function should be used inside a property of a React component, called validate, which receives a value when the function is fired. I want this argument to be sent in to my inner function as the argument c. How to to that propperly?

Inside another file I am thinking of something like this, but I do not know if this is right. Can someone explain me how I can do what I want?

```
validate = (value) => {
  const { propA, propB } = this.props;
  return myFunc(propA, propB)(value);
}

render() {
  return <MyComponent validate={this.validate} />
}
```

Comment: `myFunc(propA, propB)(value)` is the correct syntax

Comment: Have you tried it yet? Did it work?

Answer (score 0):

What I described in the question worked just fine!